# VB Script - Reading Multiple XML Nodes in one line?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vbscript

Having trouble reading a certain format of XML Nodes that's driving me and my partner nuts...

we've tried this.. but we keep getting "blank" msgboxs.. any help would be very well appreciated

```
Set xmlObject = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
urlPath = "C:\Users\...\Desktop\LolChampsSelect.xml"

xmlObject.async = False
xmlObject.load urlPath

'set ban = xmlObject.selectNodes("//*")
set ban = xmlObject.selectNodes("//*")
set ban = xmlObject.selectNodes("//red/ban[@order]
msgbox ban(0).text
```

XML FILE

```
 <championSelect>
       <blue>
         <ban order="1" name="Darius"/>
         <ban order="3" name="Elise" />
         <ban order="5" name="Twisted Fate" />
         <pick order="1" name="Gragas" />
         <pick order="4" name="Shen" />
         <pick order="5" name="Shyvanna" />
```

Comment: Your XML (as far as I can see it) has no text, only attribute values.

Comment: ah makes sense.  i'll tell the developer they have to change their XML output.  thank you so much for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimal demo code for dealing with attributes:

```
  Dim sXml : sXml = Join(Array(_
        "<championSelect>" _
      , " <blue>" _
      , "  <ban order=""1"" name=""Darius""/>" _
      , "  <ban order=""3"" name=""Elise"" />" _
      , " </blue>" _
      , "</championSelect>" _
  ), vbCrLf)
  Dim objMSXML : Set objMSXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
  objMSXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  objMSXML.async = False
  objMSXML.loadXml sXml

  If 0 = objMSXML.parseError Then
     Dim ndFound : Set ndFound = objMSXML.SelectSingleNode("/championSelect/blue/ban[@order=""3""]")
     WScript.Echo ndFound.tagName, "found"
     WScript.Echo "name:", ndFound.getAttribute("name")
  Else
     WScript.Echo objMSXML.parseError.reason
  End If
```

output:

```
==============
ban found
name: Elise
==============
```

use this to lookup objects/functions/properties in the docs.